# Parse file and redirect from Apache config file

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd.conf

This is no doubt a no but has anyone has experienced reading and redirecting the request in apache based on a config rule?

EG:

```
<If "!%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#files/cache/static/[A-Za-z_\-0-9]+.cache# && -f '/var/www/files/cache/static/%{tolower:%{REQUEST_URI}}.cache'">
           #Read /files/cache/static/xyz.cache and redirect to url in contents
</If>
```

I need to be able to read the contents of a file and redirect to the url specified.

This would allow apache to deal with a dynamic image request instead of it going through PHP.

I'm already doing something similar with HTML pages and it works beautifully but images I want to avoid having a "cached" copy of the image and would like to redirect to the actual file without involving an additional parser.

EDIT for clarity:

User 1 visits **example.com/username-128-128.jpg**

PHP then parses the url and retrieves the image at the right size and scale (either generating it or retrieving from file storage)

say the actual image is **/var/www/files/images/username/128/128/image.jpg**

PHP creates a file name "**username-128-128.jpg.cache**" file in **/var/www/files/cache/static** which contains "**example.com/files/images/username/128/128/image.jpg**" and then redirects to the actual file

Header("Location: **example.com/files/images/username/128/128/image.jpg**");

User 2: Requests the same file **example.com/username-128-128.jpg**

Apache see's there is a file "**/var/www/files/cache/static/username-128-128.jpg.cache**" it then reads that file and uses mod_rewrite to redirect to the contents of the file.

What i'm trying to avoid is creating a copy of **/var/www/files/images/username/128/128/image.jpg** 
in 
**/var/www/files/cache/static/**

Because it's wasteful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your logic is backward but mod_rewrite may help you:

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
RewriteMap nocache "txt:/files/cache/static/xyz.cache"
RewriteCond /var/www/files/cache/static/${lc:%{REQUEST_URI}}.cache !-f
RewriteRule files/cache/static/[A-Za-z_\-0-9]+.cache ${nocache:foo} [L]
```

Rather than putting just the destination URL in `/files/cache/static/xyz.cache` you'd have to put a map:

```
foo http://wwww.example.com/actual_file
```

or

```
foo /actual_file
```

`foo` could be a variable as well.

Comment: I've edited my question to make it clearer. I understand how to do the above but we're dealing with images. I don't want to make another copy of an image just for the sake of cache handling